# ZingChart Zoom Date issue

Tags: javascript, charts, zingchart

When I do a zoom on a date in the x-axis the chart gets stuck.

This happens only when I work with longs.
With dates it works fine.
I'm new in zing charts and I'm not sure what i am doing wrong

```
  zingchart.exec('myChart', 'zoomtovalues', {
       'xmin':1425312000000,
       'xmax':1425657600000,
 });
```

and my values are

```
  "values": [
    [1425225600000,1],
    [1425312000000,1],
    [1425398400000,1],
    [1425484800000,1],
    [1425571200000,1],
    [1425657600000,1],
    [1425744000000,1],
    [1425826800000,1],
    [1425913200000,1],
    [1425999600000,1]
    ],
```

**UPDATE**

The reason the chart was getting stuck was the step, It works without scrollX

```
scaleX:{
label:{},
minValue:1425196800000,
step:"day",
  transform: {
    type: 'date',
  all:"%m/%d/%y"
  }
},
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have not given much information related to your chart or chart configuration. Based on what you are saying I'm taking a wild guess at what you are asking. If I'm wrong feel feel to follow up.

What you are missing is the `scrollX` attribute. This enables the scrollbar. Another option is to enable the `preview` window. Both of these options work in cohesion with zooming.

Information related to `scrollX`, `preview` and `zooming` in general.
https://www.zingchart.com/docs/tutorials/interactive-features/chart-zoom-pan-scroll/

https://www.zingchart.com/docs/api/json-configuration/graphset/scroll-x-scroll-y/

https://www.zingchart.com/docs/api/json-configuration/graphset/preview/

```js
var myConfig = {
  type: 'line', 
    title: {
      text: 'After 2 seconds call API method \`zoomtovalues\`'
    },
  scaleX:{
    transform: {
      type: 'date',
    }
  },
  scrollX:{},
 series: [
  {
   values: [
        [1425225600000,1],
        [1425312000000,1],
        [1425398400000,1],
        [1425484800000,1],
        [1425571200000,1],
        [1425657600000,1],
        [1425744000000,1],
        [1425826800000,1],
        [1425913200000,1],
        [1425999600000,1]
      ],
  }
 ]
};

setTimeout(function() {
 zingchart.exec('myChart', 'zoomtovalues', {
   'xmin':1425312000000,
   'xmax':1425657600000,
 });
}, 2000);

zingchart.render({ 
 id: 'myChart', 
 data: myConfig, 
 height: '100%', 
 width: '100%' 
});
```

```css
html, body {
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
#myChart {
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 min-height:150px;
}
.zc-ref {
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <!--Assets will be injected here on compile. Use the assets button above-->
  <script src= "https://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="myChart"><a class="zc-ref" href="https://www.zingchart.com">Powered by ZingChart</a></div>
 </body>
</html>
```